# How to completely exclude a folder from compiling in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion

I want to basically have a "trash" folder in one of my CLion projects which I can just use to dump all .cpp or whatever files that I do not want to compile. So the files that I do want to compile will be in a "main" folder and if I feel like adding a new file, I can just copy it from the "trash" folder.

This can be done in Eclipse by simply making a new "empty project" but CLion doesn't seem to have that option.

Maybe some CMake code to exclude a directory since CLion primarily relies on CMake for project building?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. I simply added the following code to CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB Sourcefiles Source/*.cpp)
add_executable(project_name ${Sourcefiles})
```

where "Source" is a folder at root level of the project folder; it will hold all the main files and "project_name" is simply the name of the project.

This way CMake just looks through that folder for files that are meant to be compiled and ignores everything else. This works great in CLion where I can use the "Reload CMake Project" option to tell CMake about new files added.